# How to add up two numbers gotten from firebase with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

Am new to React, and it feels like its very difficult to carry out mathematical calculations with react, Have been trying to add up two values gotten from firebase database but it keeps displaying the values as string and not adding the two values, Please I need help.

{contactObjects[id].gcc} + {contactObjects[id].lcc}
adding this two will only display all as string

E.g
if {contactObjects[id].gcc} is = 10 in firebase datebase and {contactObjects[id].lcc} as = 30

And adding + to the code wont sum up the two values, it will only display them as
10 + 30 which is in string and not 40

Please how can i go about it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ContactForm from "./ContactForm";
import firebaseDb from "../firebase";

const Contacts = () => {
  var [contactObjects, setContactObjects] = useState({});
  var [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    firebaseDb.child("contacts").on("value", (snapshot) => {
      if (snapshot.val() != null)
        setContactObjects({
          ...snapshot.val(),
        });
      else setContactObjects({});
    });
  }, []); // similar to componentDidMount

  const addOrEdit = (obj) => {
    if (currentId == "")
      firebaseDb.child("contacts").push(obj, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else setCurrentId("");
      });
    else
      firebaseDb.child(`contacts/${currentId}`).set(obj, (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else setCurrentId("");
      });
  };

  const onDelete = (key) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure to delete this record?")) {
      debugger;
      firebaseDb.child(`contacts/${key}`).remove((err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else setCurrentId("");
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div className="container">
          <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Contact Register</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-5">
          <ContactForm {...{ addOrEdit, currentId, contactObjects }} />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-7">
          <table className="table table-borderless table-stripped">
            <thead className="thead-light">
              <tr>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Mobile</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Street</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Gcc</th>
                <th>Lcc</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {Object.keys(contactObjects).map((id) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={id}>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].fullName}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].mobile}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].email}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].address}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].street}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].gcc}</td>
                    <td>{contactObjects[id].lcc}</td>
                    <td>
                      {contactObjects[id].gcc} +
                      {contactObjects[id].lcc}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a
                        className="btn text-primary"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setCurrentId(id);
                        }}
                      >
                        <i className="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i>
                      </a>
                      <a
                        className="btn text-danger"
                        onClick={() => {
                          onDelete(id);
                        }}
                      >
                        <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Contacts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then just parse these values to int. If in DB these are 'string'

`{parseInt(contactObjects[id].gcc) + parseInt(contactObjects[id].lcc)}`